# escape the characters php with javascript inside,correct syntax quotes

Tags: javascript, php, escaping

how should be the correct syntax of quotes for this piece of code ?

```
<?php

    $cod="<div id='id1' onclick='xmlhttpPost(index.php?ajax="'this.id'") class='divazienda'>".$row[0];

?>
```

my problem is that I do not take the result of this.id of the js

Comment: Try `$cod="<div id='id1' onclick='xmlhttpPost(index.php?ajax=' + this.id + ') class='divazienda'>".$row[0];`

Comment: try this $cod="<div id='id1' onclick='xmlhttpPost(index.php?ajax='" + this.id + "') class='divazienda'>".$row[0];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $cod="<div id=\"id1\" onclick=\"xmlhttpPost('index.php?ajax=' + this.id);\" class=\"divazienda\">".$row[0];
```

Escape double quotes (for each of the div attributes) as they are within the php double quotes

As you are passing a string with the current element id into the onclick function - the string part needs to be in quotes and the variable part needs to be out of the quotes